# Convert string(object) column of dataframe to numeric by applying some string formatting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

Take pandas dataframe as

```
index           A    
    0       1qwe 3asd
    1       6qwe 35asd
    2       11qwe 13asd
    3       17qwe 8asd
    4       5qwe 9asd
    5       7qwe 2asd
    6       1qwe 20asd

A.dtype = object
```

Convert this dataframe as follows

```
index        A    
    0       1.03
    1       6.35
    2       11.13
    3       17.08
    4       5.09
    5       7.02
    6       1.20

A.dtype = float64
```

Is conversion possible in python? If yes, please give code in efficient way.

After period(.) padding of zero should take place if only one digit is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one `str.replace` call,

```
df['A'].str.replace(r'(\d+).*?(\d+).*', lambda x: '{}.{:0>2}'.format(x[1], x[2]))
```

---

```
pd.to_numeric(df['A'].str.replace(
  r'(\d+).*?(\d+).*', lambda x: '{}.{:0>2}'.format(x[1], x[2])), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you, please take a look at edited question. After period(.) padding of zero should take place if only one digit is present

Comment: @Jayant there was a bug in which numbers with two decimal places weren't handled correctly. I've fixed it now!

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), [`apply.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df.A.str.findall('(\d+)').apply('.'.join))

0     1.30
1     6.35
2    11.13
3    17.80
4     5.90
5     7.20
6     1.20
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please take look at edited question and answer how it can be done?